# Dont get all the Web elements in the Arraylist of webelement selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I dont get all the Web elements in the Arraylist of webelement selenium webdriver in java .Increasing the thread sleep time gives successful result but it increases the execution time of code

Comment: Please provide the code , this has too little information for anyone to answer

Comment: It seems that your elements are rendered by JS, which makes them impossible to be found right after your web finishs loading. So, if you need to wait for those elements, but don't want to waste much time to wait, you have to use `explicit` wait or `fluent` wait to achieve. If you need help at coding, please provide more detail about your elements and conditions.